# define a new Example environment

Tags: environments, examples

how can i define a new `Example` environment like the image shown in the following?

this environment should have the following attributes:

- endmarks must be positioned at the last line, whether it includes text or formula; but in formula mode, the red square must be positioned at left side.
- if the word `Example` and its red sub-line arrive at the end of page, and there was no more space to include the body of example, the whole `example` must be inserted at next page (the `section, subsection, ...` have this property by default).

[image]

Comment: IMHO, having the end-marks in different positions introduces inconsistencies in your document. I would suggest you to use just one positioning option for the end-marks.

Comment: Could you show what you have so far? Positioning the end-marks conditionally will be tricky- the algorithm to get the correct when they are on just one side is pretty long- see the `ntheorem` package for details

Comment: @smh I've updated my answer providing some code to achieve what you want.

Comment: Just out of curiosity about the spell checking: What PDF viewer are you using here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is just a partial answer (for a complete answer, go to the last exampe). I used the [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package as a front-end for `amsthm` to define a theorem-like structure.

The use of

```
  \interlinepenalty 10000
```

in `postheadhook` prevents pagebreaks as requested.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
headfont=\normalfont\color{myred},
notefont=\mdseries\color{myred}, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=\newline,
headpunct=,
numberwithin=chapter,
postheadhook=\leavevmode%
  \interlinepenalty 10000%
  \vskip-1.3\baselineskip%
  \noindent{\color{myred}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}%
  \interlinepenalty 10000%
  \vskip0.3\baselineskip\noindent,
qed=\textcolor{myred}{$\blacksquare$}
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{example}

\renewcommand\theexample{\thechapter-\arabic{example}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
%\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{example}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The *only* thing that remains unsolved is the positioning of the end-mark when the last line in the environment belongs to a displayed math expression. Quite frankly I wouldn't know how to conditionally change the end-mark placement.

Here's another possibility using this time the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package; the end-mark is provided using the `\xqed` macro defined in the document linked in the page [Theorems in AMS-LaTeX](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=212) of the AMS-FAQ.:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\xqed}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
  \quad\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{\stepcounter{example}}
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\xqed{\textcolor{myred}{\blacksquare}}}

\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}

\newmdenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  frametitle={Example~\theexample},
  frametitlerule=true,
  frametitlerulecolor=myred,
  frametitlerulewidth=2pt,
  frametitlefont=\bfseries\color{myred},
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt
]{example}

\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\renewcommand\theexample{\thechapter-\arabic{example}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{example}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's now a possible complete solution; instead of conditionally redefining the behaviour of the end-marks (which could be really difficult), the user can manually select the `lexample` environment which behaves like `example`, but placing the end-mark to the left:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\mylen

\newcommand{\xxqed}[1]{%
  \settowidth\mylen{$#1$}%
  \vskip-2\baselineskip\hspace*{-\mylen}\llap{\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\xqed}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
  \quad\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{\stepcounter{example}}
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\xqed{\textcolor{myred}{\blacksquare}}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{lexample}{\stepcounter{example}}
\AtEndEnvironment{lexample}{\xxqed{\textcolor{myred}{\blacksquare}}}

\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}

\newmdenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  frametitle={Example~\theexample},
  frametitlerule=true,
  frametitlerulecolor=myred,
  frametitlerulewidth=2pt,
  frametitlefont=\bfseries\color{myred},
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  skipabove=.6\topskip,
  skipbelow=.6\topskip
]{lexample}

\newmdenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  frametitle={Example~\theexample},
  frametitlerule=true,
  frametitlerulecolor=myred,
  frametitlerulewidth=2pt,
  frametitlefont=\bfseries\color{myred},
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  skipabove=.6\topskip,
  skipbelow=.6\topskip
]{example}

\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\renewcommand\theexample{\thechapter-\arabic{example}}

\newcommand\Text{% just to generate text for the example
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus
tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In
hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis.
Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed
gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim.
Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl.
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{lexample}
\Text
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
&= c 
\end{align}
\end{lexample}
\Text
\begin{example}
\Text
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Initially, I deleted this answer since it was not complete, but since no other answers have been provided, perhaps this one can help.

Comment: Actually my only idea is, that the human being aka the author must decide manually, whether the endmark has to be left or right. This could either be done with two very similar environments or better with a key driven variant as in `keycommand`. And how to get the square in ltr mode to left of the last line _before_ the last part of the equation!?!? Something like `\llap{\xqed\hspace*{\linewidth}}` (with `calc`: `\linewidth` minus width of `\xqed`)?

Comment: @Speravir yes; I've implemented your suggestion in my last example code; now the user selects which environment to use: `example` (with end-mark to the right) or `lexample` (with end-mark to the left).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- it looks like something has gone wrong here; the gap between text and the `align` is larger than i'm used to seeing it, especially since there's such tight spacing between the end of it and the following text, and the end marker looks like it might be positioned a hair above that last baseline.  (ams classes default to put display numbers on the left, so there's no conflict with a right-aligned "tombstone".)

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're right about the larger gap; I'll have to check that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did some tests, suppressing the `lexample` environment and the gap remains the same, so I think the behaviour is the standard one. Do you get a different result suppressing the environment?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added some spacing (`\topskip`) above and below the environments to improve the layout; I hope things look better now.

Comment: i've just tried a much simpler test, with input text (not `\lipsum`} before and after the same `align` as in your example.  there's a much larger space above the `align` when `\lipsum` is used.  so i think the problem is in the way `\lipsum` terminates -- possibly a `\par`.  as we know, that would have this effect.  (i don't have the current `lipsum` package, using the one from 2010, but i suspect this is something that wouldn't have changed unless someone reported it before, and i don't remember seeing that mentioned anywhere.)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- with `\topskip` at least it looks more balanced.  but really spacier than i think is ideal.  but see my previous comment re `\lipsum`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I changed to `0.6\topskip` and it looks better (I hope so); I also dropped `lipsum` and used some custom text instead.

Comment: yes, better.  i have to leave now; i'll check tomorrow.

Comment: How can you add a similar finishing line to the example?