# how to define a new section-like environment

Tags: sectioning

If a `section` heading arrives at the end of a page, and there is no more space to include the later text body, the section heading will be shifted to the next page (the section, subsection, ..., all have this property, by default).

Now, I want to define a new section-like environment. This environment has a red line below of its heading and we can insert our text underneath this line.

Comment: Why does it need to be a new environment? The `titlesec` package for instance lets you configure section titles.

Comment: Perhaps [`this answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86831/3954) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86825/3954 can be useful in this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic \newpage for sections at the end of a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70907/automatic-newpage-for-sections-at-the-end-of-a-page) and  [Avoiding page breaks shortly after section/subsection headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/avoiding-page-breaks-shortly-after-section-subsection-headings).