# Cannot add pictures to new environment

Tags: floats, environments

I copy pasted an environment I found [around here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86825/define-a-new-example-environment) to create an "Example" section as defined below:

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\mylen

\newcommand{\xxqed}[1]{%
  \settowidth\mylen{$#1$}%
  \vskip-2\baselineskip\hspace*{-\mylen}\llap{\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\xqed}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
  \quad\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{\stepcounter{example}}
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\xqed{\textcolor{black}{\blacksquare}}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{lexample}{\stepcounter{example}}
\AtEndEnvironment{lexample}{\xxqed{\textcolor{black}{\blacksquare}}}

\colorlet{myred}{black}

\newmdenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  frametitle={Example~\theexample},
  frametitlerule=true,
  frametitlerulecolor=black,
  frametitlerulewidth=2pt,
  frametitlefont=\bfseries,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  skipabove=.6\topskip,
  skipbelow=.6\topskip
]{lexample}

\newmdenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  frametitle={Example~\theexample},
  frametitlerule=true,
  frametitlerulecolor=black,
  frametitlerulewidth=2pt,
  frametitlefont=\bfseries,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  skipabove=.6\topskip,
  skipbelow=.6\topskip
]{example}

\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\renewcommand\theexample{\thesection.\arabic{example}}
```

But, when I added a picture (with the normal \begin{figure} and \includegraphics) to this environment it gives an error compiling and it does not add the picture.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome on  TeX.SX ! \\ I didn't used `mdframed` for years as I find `tcolorbox` much more powerful and convenient. But it looks very strange to patch the macro related to `example` environment with `AtBeginEnvironment` and sibling *before* to define them! \\ By the way, at  least with `tcolorbox` the numbering could be directily setup in the environment definition itself...\\ Finally, it is not really  consistent  to try to add floats in this boxed stuff.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't reallt understand what you say and how to implement changes in order for this to work. I took this code from this post: 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86825/define-a-new-example-environment

Comment: I don't see how the quoted  example can even work. But If it works, your ms8n pronlem is with the floating `figure` that can not be hosted in such a context. If you need to insertva picture, you can use a  *bare* `\includegrophics`, or wrap it In a `minipage`.  I could privide a full example with `tcolorbox`, but it's night here, and of nobody does thatvin the interval, you will have to wait a few hours...

Comment: In any cases  please help us to help you by editing your question to provide a full minimal (non-) working example (aka MWE) starting with `\documemtclass` and closing with `\end{documemt}`. And also add to it the reference of the TSx answer that you used.

Comment: What you show in the code block is irrelevant.  The relevant bit here is that you say you use `\begin{figure}`.  That will never work -- `figure` is a floating environment, and it will be placed where LaTeX thinks it should go, not necessarily where you input it.  What you should do instead is use just `\includegraphics` and `\captionof, which will stay where you specify them.  *Never* try to nest a float (`figure`m `table`, some others) inside another environment,

Comment: Please provide your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: You are right guys, figure does not work as a float. I removed this environment; how would you suggest something similar to the example shown here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86825/define-a-new-example-environment

Comment: well, I have solved the issue with figure as you have suggested:

I added the figure as suggested, without the "figure" environment and using:

`
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{imgs/Image.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{Caption for figure.}
\end{center}
`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I have solved the issue with figure as you have suggested. I added the figure as suggested, without the "figure" environment and using:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{imgs/Image.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{Caption for figure.}
\end{center}
```